# Seems like the SWT redrawing commands are skipped that leads to appearing artifacts on the screen

Tags: java, swt

I’ve encountered with the following problem related to the `Control.redraw(int, int, int, int, boolean)` method called on Canvas. I’m working on the diagram editor. Recently I’ve implemented the selection tool. It shows a rectangular frame on the diagram. The problem is that I get artifacts on the screen when I resize quickly this selection tool with help of mouse. But everything is redrawn correctly when I resize the tool slowly.

In the SWT language it looks as follows.

Each time the selection rectangle is resized with help of mouse, I eventually call the `redraw` method specifying the corresponded rectangle area to redraw. Then I catch the `PaintEvent` and paint the frame. Everything works as expected if the mouse movement is slow.

The questions is can SWT skip the painting events or skip the redraw commands? Does anybody encountered with a similar issue? Maybe, is there some flag that should be set?

So, I tried to `setRedraw(true)` but it didn’t give any effect. Finally, I tried to replace the `redraw(int, int, int, int, boolean)` method with just `redraw()` and the artifacts disappeared but this is not acceptable solution as it created sensible lags at time of resizing the selection tool, especially on Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether every single call to redraw is matched with paint event, then the answer is no. It's possible that OS will decide to merge several redraw requests into one paint event (which, nonetheless, should cover the area of all original requests). Note that paint requests can be triggered using `update()` method - `redraw()` will simply invalidate an area and mark it for repaint, but doesn't explicitly trigger the repaint.

It's possible that OS has some problems with repaints, but it is far more likely that the problem is in your painting code/redraw algorithm.

Comment: You are right. There is some wrong with my coordinates. Probably, the affine transformation is incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it was completely my mistake. SWT works fine. I just forgot to send a signal to redraw the area before updating... while I did it only after updating the selection tool. The equations and affine transformation are absolutely correct.